# C Compilation Error Following README

Tags: bitcoin-core, c

I'm having an issue getting the local bitcoin client running on a Mac OS X machine.

When installing berkeley-db4, and running the following command (per the README):

```
brew install https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Formula/berkeley-db4.rb -–without-java
```

I then enter the console, and run `cd ..` and then:

```
db-4.8.30/dist/configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/berkeley-db4/4.8.30 --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/berkeley-db4/4.8.30/share/man --enable-cxx
```

Once that happens, I get a long trace ending in this error. Has anyone run into this?

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/private/tmp/berkeley-db420160220-8656-19l1688':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Comment: I don't have a Mac, so I can't reproduce this, but a google search suggests that the problem might be caused by not having glibc, gcc, or make.

Comment: Does not sound as if this is bitcoin related, maybe StackOverflow might be a better place to ask questions relating to dev-setup?

Comment: Thanks for the notes -- only reason I posted here was in case there was an error in the README that could be spotted. @nickodell will try out glibc (seems like I have the others installled)